# What does struct mean in variable definition? c++

Tags: c++, c, struct

[Here](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#intro) I've found a variable definition which looks this way:

```
struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
```

It seems to be defining a pointer to a variable of type `struct sockaddr`, but

1)struct is a keyword

2)`struct sockaddr test;` creates error

```
aggregate 'sockaddr test' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

(I work under gcc 4.7.1)

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html

Comment: I guess `2) struct sockaddr ai_addrr; creates error` should be read `2) struct sockaddr test; creates error`, no?

Comment: In C (not C++ !) the name `structure` in `struct structure` is not a type by itself. `struct structure` is the type (thats why you see typedef struct structure structure_type in C code)

Comment: @Alfonso Nishikawa. Yes, changed it.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking I didn't use pure C. Thanks.

Comment: @user2136963 You do, struct sockaddr is extern "C"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this statement

```
struct sockaddr *ai_addr;
```

there is used so-called elaborated type specifier. This statement does two things. First of all it declares type name `sockaddr` and declares a pointer of this type.

To declare a pointer to a structure there is no need that the structure would be defined that is that it would be a complete type because the size of the pointer does not depend on the size of the structure.

For this statement

```
struct sockaddr ai_addr;
```

the compiler issues an error because it needs to allocate memory for the object of type `struct sockaddr`but it doesn not know the size of the structure because the structure was not yet defined. That is the structure is an incomplete type. It is only declared but not yet defined and its size is unknown.

Comment: For `struct sockaddr ai_addr` just comment that if `struct sockaddr` is not declared will throw the same error. For example if forgot the proper include.

Comment: @Alfonso Nishikawa  Elaborated type specifier is a declaration. So you need no any other preceding declaration of the structure.

Comment: I just was taking about the possibility of having forgot to put the proper include. In that case `struct sockaddr ai_addr` will show the same error... at least for my gcc (4.8.2). Your answer is correct, no doubt about that.

Answer (score -1):

struct is not really a simple data type. It's rather a complex data type which works like data structure, where you can hold different types of data together. For example, if you want to hold the data of a business card in a structure (which is declared by struct keyword), you can define it like this:

```
struct bizcard {
  char name[30];
  char organization[50];
  char email[50];
};
```

Another example:

```
struct student {
  char name[30];
  int registration_no;
  float cgpa;
}
```

For more info, check : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)

Comment: All structs I used to work with could be defined like `sockaddr test;` in case `sockaddr` is structure. But there I cannot create a `sockaddr` variable. Only pointer to it and only with `struct` keyword in definition of a variable.

Comment: You should be able to write struct sockaddr test; to declare a structure named test of type sockaddr.

Comment: *struct is not really a data type*  Perhaps in `C`, but in `C++` a `struct` is a datatype.

Comment: You are correct, I should have written, struct is not really a simple data type. :)